# How would I code an array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am trying to make Delphi talk to the WinAPI function [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromhmonitor).

How would I setup the needed data structure?

Currently, I have:

```pascal
  LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR = record
    hPhysicalMonitor: THandle;
    szPhysicalMonitorDescription: array [0..127] of WideChar;
  end;
  PLPPHYSICAL_MONITOR = ^LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR;
```

However, the function expects an **array** – and I need an array, when I dereference the Pointer structure in order to get first, second ... monitor.

This is what I have for the function itself:

```pascal
function GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor: HMONITOR;
   dwPhysicalMonitorArraySize: DWORD;
   pPhysicalMonitorArray: PLPPHYSICAL_MONITOR): Boolean;
   stdcall; external 'Dxva2.dll' Name 'GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the same documentation you linked to:

> To get the required size of the array, call [`GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getnumberofphysicalmonitorsfromhmonitor).

So, get the array size first, then allocate the array, then pass the array to `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()`.  The same documentation you linked to even provides an example of that (in C, which can easily be translated to Delphi).

Try something like this:

```pascal
const
  PHYSICAL_MONITOR_DESCRIPTION_SIZE = 128;

type
  PHYSICAL_MONITOR = record
    hPhysicalMonitor: THandle;
    szPhysicalMonitorDescription: array[0..PHYSICAL_MONITOR_DESCRIPTION_SIZE-1] of WideChar;
  end;
  LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR = ^PHYSICAL_MONITOR;

function GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor: HMONITOR;
  pdwNumberOfPhysicalMonitors: LPDWORD): BOOL;
  stdcall; external 'Dxva2.dll' name 'GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR';

function GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor: HMONITOR;
  dwPhysicalMonitorArraySize: DWORD;
  pPhysicalMonitorArray: LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR): BOOL;
  stdcall; external 'Dxva2.dll' name 'GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR';

function DestroyPhysicalMonitors(dwPhysicalMonitorArraySize: DWORD;
  LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitorArray): _BOOL;
  stdcall; external 'Dxva2.dll' name 'DestroyPhysicalMonitors';
```

```pascal
var
  hMonitor: HMONITOR;
  cPhysicalMonitors, I: DWORD;
  pPhysicalMonitors: array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR;
begin
  // Get the monitor handle.
  hMonitor = ...;

  // Get the number of physical monitors.
  if not GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, @cPhysicalMonitors) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  if cPhysicalMonitors = 0 then
    Exit;

  // Allocate the array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR structures.
  SetLength(pPhysicalMonitors, cPhysicalMonitors);

  // Get the array.
  if not GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, @pPhysicalMonitors[0]) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    for I := 0 to cPhysicalMonitors-1 do
    begin
      // Use pPhysicalMonitors[I] as needed.
    end;
  finally
    // Close the monitor handles.
    DestroyPhysicalMonitors(cPhysicalMonitors, @pPhysicalMonitors[0]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Merci. Seems to work. I was missing the dynamic array.